# Simplest vanilla JavaScript way to pair items from a unidimensional array into a multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Currently I have a unidimensional array, e.g. `['thing1', 'cond1', 'thing2', 'cond2', 'thing3']`

I would like to pair each item to create a new multidimensional array like so `[['thing1', 'cond1'], ['thing2', 'cond2'], ['thing3']]`. I don't mind the last item being `['thing3', undefined]` – if anything this is preferable unless someone raises this as bad practice.

So far I have

```
const pair = (arr) => {
  let paired = [];

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
    paired.push([arr[i], arr[i+1]]);
  }

  return paired;
}
```

You can try this out in my [JS Bin example](https://jsbin.com/joleraf/edit?js,console).

This works perfectly fine AFAIA but I'd love this to be as concise as possible using modern JS and I'm not as polished as I should be with my array manipulation.

Thanks in advance to everyone who gives this a go.

Let the challenge... BEGIN!

Comment: Other than the fact that `i` should be declared with `let`, I don't see anything wrong with that. It's readable and short.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a `while` loop with an index variable. For pushing a pair take `slice`.

```js
const pair = array => {
    let paired = [],
        i = 0;

    while (i < array.length) paired.push(array.slice(i, i += 2));

    return paired;
}

var array = ['thing1', 'cond1', 'thing2', 'cond2', 'thing3'],
    paired = pair(array);

console.log(paired);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `regex`. Group the values by finding the number by using regular expression.

```js
const data = ['thing1', 'cond1', 'thing2', 'cond2', 'thing3'];
const result = {};

data.forEach(value => {
 const index = value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
    if (typeof result[index] == 'undefined') {
     result[index] = [];
    }
    result[index].push(value);
});

const array = Object.values(result);
console.log(array);
```